# Redirect To Route within Function React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a button with a click event that calls a function that makes an API to login a user, once a user has been successfully logged in. I want to redirect the user to `/overview`. I'm not entirely sure how to do it with `react-router-dom`, everything I have seen has been with `react-router` and using a `Class Based Component` and not a `Function Based Component` like I am using.

Below is how my Routes are setup

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from "../../login/Login";
import Main from "../../main/Main";

const App = () => {

   return (
      <div className="App">
         <Router>
            <div className="App-container">
               <Route path={"/login"} component={() => <Login />} />
               <Route exact path={"/overview"} component={Main} />
            </div>
         </Router>
      </div>
   );

}

export default App;
```

Here is my LoginCard Component (Inside Login Component) with the button and function with the api call

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '../button/Button';
import LoginService from '../../api/LoginService';

const LoginCard = (props) => {

   const loginService = new LoginService();

   const handleLogin = () => {
      loginService.login(email, password)
         .then((response) => {
            // Want to redirect here?
         });
   }

   return (
      <div className="Login">
         <Button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</Button>
      </div>
   );
};

export default LoginCard;
```

Here is what I have tried but hasn't worked from looking at other threads

`<Redirect to="/overview"/>`
`<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/overview' }} />`

I also saw people mention `props.location` or `this.props.location` both are undefined for me.

Tried to add

```
import createBrowserHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
const history = createBrowserHistory();
<Router history={history}>
```

in App.js and the use
`history.push`
But got an error saying it was not a function.

So not really sure how to do this? I'd rather only solve this with `react-router-dom` or via a `Function Based Component`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `LoginCard` is a child component of `Login` it will not get access to the [`route props`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) automatically. You can either change your `Route` to the following, and pass down the `history` prop from `Login` to `LoginCard`:

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```

Or you can use the [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC to inject the `route props` into the `LoginCard` component.

```
const LoginCard = props => {
  const loginService = new LoginService();

  const handleLogin = () => {
    loginService.login(email, password).then(response => {
      props.history.push("/overview");
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="Login">
      <Button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(LoginCard);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return it conditionally in your **render** method like

```
if(this.state.authenticated){
 return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/overview' }} />
}
```

and return your login ui if not authenticated as you have

```
 return (
  <div className="Login">
  <Button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</Button>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that to login user please Also look into privateRoute which help you secure your page

Please look this tutorial for more details
[react auth tutorial click here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)