# Using Redirect upon form submission in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I have been attempting to Redirect upon user login. The login works correctly with my database and will conditionally render my new links for my admin portal. I was trying to use Redirect upon getting a status code 200, but I am not sure if this is even the correct way.

axios post for Login component:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(adminLogin)

    axios
      .post("/api/Authentication", adminLogin)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
          <Redirect to="/inventory" />
        }
        setAdminLogin(response.data);
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't Redirect from function directly. If you want to redirect from function then you can use `this.props.history.push('/inventory');`

And another way to redirect using state.

```
const[login,setIsLoggedIn]=useState(false)

if (response.status === 200) {
       setIsLoggedIn(true);
}
if(login){
       return <Redirect to='/inventory'/>
}

return(
       //Main function return
);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use react-router-dom you can see this example from [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) and you can see similiar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165364/redirect-to-route-within-function-react-router-dom)

Answer (score 0):

As it is an axios call, it is always recommended to use this.props.history.push().

Make sure while using this function, you have already used withRouter to route your component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
    ...
    const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(adminLogin)

    axios
      .post("/api/Authentication", adminLogin)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
          this.props.history.push('/inventory');
        }
        setAdminLogin(response.data);
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
    ...
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

If you won't wrap your component with withRouter, history object will not be present in this.props and hence, will be throwing an error.